# Lookup attribute in journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I have a journey which has Salesforce Data as an entry source. We could pass the preferred language of this person in this entry source but could I also retrieve it through the Synchronized data extension in a decision split?

Could it also be done for the email address in the journey settings? With the "Use email attribute from Contacts"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every decision split evaluation in Journey Builder on synchronized data extensions is done based on the ContactId/LeadId/UserId (depending on the object type) of your Salesforce record.

In order to retrieve this data via email address, you'd need a separate data extension that is filled via Automation Studio and is connected to the contact model in data designer via the email address (which should be the primary key of this data extension).

You can then configure your decision split to look up the preferred language in this data extension. However, you have to consider the following thins:

- the data extension might be outdated because of the sync interval and the interval of your automation
- if you use salesforce data entry events that trigger on record creation, you most possibly won't have an entry in the helper data extension --> the remainder path will always be used --> To ensure correct function, you need to add a decision split that listens to event data (journey data) and joins into the paths for the certain languages.

Answer (score 0):

When using Salesforce Data as an entry source, I will always advice you to rely mostly on your journey data, as there will be a slight delay in getting the records synced into Salesforce Data Extensions. Especially if you have a multi-BU setup where, in addition to the sync delay from Core, you might also have additional sync running as a recurring automation.

This is mostly relevant for the initial activity on the JB canvas, as the subsequent activities usually come after one or more wait steps, allowing sufficient time for your data to synchronise.